# Is there a pythonic way to replace nan values from dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace nan values from my dictionary. 
For example, sometimes my dictionary looks like:

```
{'mean': nan, 'std': nan, 'median': nan, 'sum': 0, 'average_per_day': 0.0, 'freq': 0}
```

Now I'm doing it like this:

```
for k, v in stats_record.items():
    if math.isnan(v): 
        stats_record[k] = 0
```

Is there a more pythonic way to replace nan values from dictionary?

Comment: What is not pythonic about this?

Comment: Do you want it done using one-liner?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga For example, I'd be happy if it is possible to inject indexing instead of if statement. Conceptually, like this: stats_record[math.isnan(stats_record)] = 0

Comment: @taurus05 Yes, if it is readable.

Comment: @SangwookKim, refer to the answer below by AkshayNevrekar. That's excatly, what you want.

Comment: @taurus05 what is the advantage?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga refer to this link -> https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

Comment: @taurus05 yes, I am aware. What is the advantage in this situation?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, i think that, as it is faster to use a list comprehension then using a for loop, the same might apply when using dict comprehension. You can use `timeit` to see the difference or open a new question asking advantage of using dict comprehensions instead of using for loops.

Comment: @taurus05 what? It depends on the for-loop. A comprehension isn't just a one-line for-loop. It does something, namely, *built a list or a dict*. But in the OP's code, that isn't what is happening. You are comparing apples to oranges. For example, if the OP's dictionary is large, and there are very few `nan`s, your dict-comprehension is going to do *significantly* more work

Comment: So, what do you think is right? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @taurus05 I think this is not a good question, because it is vague, and I voted to close until the OP elaborates. The OP hasn't described what is wrong with their approach, just asked for something "more pythonic". Making everything a dict-comprehension or a list-comprehension isn't what pythonic means anyway. For loops are very pythonic.

Comment: Ah! I  see. You're right. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dict-comprehension` can be handy here.

```
import numpy as np

e = {'mean': np.nan, 'std': np.nan, 'median': np.nan, 'sum': 0, 'average_per_day': 0.0, 'freq': 0}

e = {k:v if not np.isnan(v) else 0 for k,v in e.items() }
print(e)
```

Output:

```
{'average_per_day': 0.0, 'sum': 0, 'freq': 0, 'median': 0, 'std': 0, 'mean': 0}
```

Comment: just pasting the output for reference `{'std': 0, 'sum': 0, 'median': 0, 'average_per_day': 0.0, 'freq': 0, 'mean': 0}`

Comment: @PuneetSinha added it to my answer!!

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Thank you very much for your suggestion. It looks quite nice. But I'm worrying the expression seems to contain an assignment (+dictionary construction). Currently I'm working with records > 10~100 millions and dictionaries should be made ~10M times. Is it efficient to like this?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar how is it more efficient? It seems less efficient to me. In this case you create a bunch of new dictionaries, rather than modifying a dictionary in place.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Oh, I see. Thanks for your solution. I'll go in this way.